# How do I get a checksum from unpack in hexadecimal format? 

Tags: perl, syntax, unpack

I've been trying to figure out the [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) function in Perl and can't quite figure out the whole thing.

What I have:
A string and a 16-bit hex checksum
(e.g. `"this is my string"`, `"0671"`)

I need to check that `"this is my string"` equals the checksum `'0671'`.

So I know `unpack("%16W*", $string)` will give me the 16-bit decimal value, but I need the hex representation. I know this is an easy one so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, `unpack("%16W*", $string)` gives you an integer.  To convert an integer to hex, use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

```
my $string = "this is my string";
my $expected = '0671';

my $checksum = sprintf('%04x', unpack("%16W*", $string));
print "match\n" if $checksum eq $expected;
```

If you want upper-case hex digits, use `%X` instead of `%x` (or `%04X` in this case).

Or, you could go the other way and convert your hex checksum to an integer using [hex](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html):

```
my $string = "this is my string";
my $expected = '0671';

my $checksum = unpack("%16W*", $string);
print "match\n" if $checksum == hex $expected; # now using numeric equality
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the top solution you gave was the correct one. Such a life savor, I actually started making my own I was getting so frustrated haha

Answer (score -1):

Try `unpack("b*',$string)`.

See the [pack man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) for syntax.

Comment: This gives a bit representation of the whole string